# How to run a Laravel project that is downloaded from a cPanel?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

SOLVED: My machine didn't have MySQL installed and was having a hard time installing it and I still do.

I recently downloaded a Laravel project from cPanel and I wish to work on it. But when I try to run the project I get "500 server error".

After searching on Google, I tried the following steps

```
composer update --no-scripts
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
```

This does not seem to be doing anything. How do I run the project on my local machine that I downloaded from the cPanel?

Comment: How are you trying to run it on local? Using `php artisan serve` or using just `localhost`?

Comment: You should have installed a web server like Apache or Nginx. Also, PHP is required (I'd recommend `v7.3`). Finally, a database server like MySQL. You can have all of this using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/), [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html), or many others.

Comment: What Laravel you're using? Maybe the PHP version is not compatible with your Laravel installation?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon php artisan serve

Comment: @KennyHorna i have all these installed. i'm using a mac, so i have apache preinstalled. i reinstalled php, mysql

Comment: If you say that have all that things working.. then you should use the console, enter to project directory.. then run ```composer install``` to install the dependencies (in case you didn't run this inside this folder) and to load the site just run `php artisan serve`, you should be able to go to the url returned from that command to see your site live (locally)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to see what that error is in the log file:

Log file location:

```
/storage/logs/laravel.log`
```

The `laravel.log` file mentioned above may have a date with it on the name.

The 500 error is because the stack trace is turned off in the `.env` file with `APP_DEBUG=false`which may be by design since it's on a live server.

Comment: this i get

production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `resource_categories`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `resource_categories`) at /Users/myMacbook/Projects/myProjecet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /Users/myMacbook/Projects/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)

Comment: That is a good start, you are not connecting to the database it seems. Check your connection settings in the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the files in "public_html" folder and project folder(in my case it is "LMS" folder - refer screenshot).
   [image]

2. Export the database from phpmyadmin in cPanel which is used in Laravel project
3. Go inside the Project folder(in my case LMS folder) and delete all the content inside the "public" folder. Then you will have an empty public folder inside your project folder(LMS folder)
4. Now copy and paste all the content inside "public_html" folder that is  downloaded from cPanel into the previously emptied "public" folder inside the project folder(LMS)
5. Import the exported database to locally created database
6. Change following lines in index.php file which is inside the local "public" folder

These two lines

```
require __DIR__.'/../LMS/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../LMS/bootstrap/app.php';
```

into these two

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Notice that we have removed the "LMS" in the paths

7. Go to the .env file in the project root and change these settings that matches to your local environment

   `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`

   `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

   `DB_PORT=3306`

   `DB_DATABASE=lms_trends_new`

   `DB_USERNAME=root`

   `DB_PASSWORD=root`

   `//Only for MAMP users`

   `DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`
8. Run following commands

   `$ php artisan config:cache`

   `$ composer dump-autoload`
9. Finally run your project with following command

   `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

First , Download the database from cpanel which is used in laravel project .

Then follow any one step below .

1. Upload the database in your localhost mysql .

   - then Change your env files as per your local system .
   - Install composer using following command .

     `composer install`
   - Then update the compsoser From your composer.json file .
     `Composer update`
     `composer dump-autoload`
   - Now run php artisan serve

If you find any difficult in the first step , follow the second one.

Install new laravel project  using following command .

```
  `composer global require laravel/installer`
```

Create new project Laravel

```
 `laravel new projectname`
```

Then just copy paste the directories app/ , Resources, /Public , /config .

Do not touch anything inside config/config.php

Just change the database name and username, password in .env file ..

Then run 
`php artisan serve`

If you still cant able to do it , comment here